# How to find all circles that have their center in their intercection a main circle

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Is there a clean way to find all the circles that are not only intersection with a main circle but also have their center inside the intersection with that main circle.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the geometric type circle, or the Postgis type CircularString or CurvePolygon? This is probably a better match for [dba.se]. You can flag it and ask the moderators to move it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's simple. You need to use `@@` or `center` to get the center point and then `@>` to use contains.

```
SELECT
  x AS r_value,
  circle('0,0', x) @> @@ circle('2,3', 1) AS contains
FROM generate_series(1,5) AS gs(x);
```

-or-

```
SELECT
  x AS r_value,
  circle('0,0', x) @> center(circle('2,3', 1)) AS contains
FROM generate_series(1,5) AS gs(x);
```

This brute-force tests circles with the center at the origin, with a radius of `[1,5]` whether they contain the center of `circle('2,3',1)`.

See the docs on [geometry functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from circles a , circles b
 where st_intersects(a.geom,st_centroid(b.geom))
```

Also, you can filter the results by adding condition in where clause. I am assuming main circle name.

```
select * from circles a , circles b
 where st_intersects(a.geom,st_centroid(b.geom))  and a.circle_name = 'Main Circle';
```